# Django front end user restrictions

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a question which might be repeated multiple times but I'm unable to understand any of them at all.

I have a view, in the view the user selects a value from a choice drop down and enters a integer amount to process.

If the user enters lets say 5 in the Quantity and he has 2 leaves remaining in the selected choice, I want him to be notified after submitting the form or on the very page that you don't have this many leaves to apply for.

**view.py**

```py
def request_leave(request, emp_id):  # Requesting leave
    employee = Employee.objects.get(employee_name=emp_id)
    if employee.allowed == True:
        form = Leave_Form(request.POST, employee=employee)
        if form.is_valid():
            abc = form.save(commit=False)
            abc.employee_leaves = request.user.employee
            abc.save()
        form = Leave_Form
        context = {'employee': employee, 'form': form}
        # context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'projectfiles/reqleave.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, "projectfiles/banned.html")
```

**models.py**

```py
class Employee(models.Model):

    allowed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    employee_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    employee_designation = models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    employee_department = models.CharField(max_length = 5)
    Annual_leave = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=5)
    Sick_leave = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=5)
    Casual_leave = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=5)
    Half_pay = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=5)
    Emergency_leave = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=5)
```

**forms.py**

```py
to_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%y'),
                               attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                      'placeholder': ' Month/Date/Year'}))


    from_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%y'),
                               attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                               'placeholder':' Month/Date/Year'}))


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        employee = kwargs.pop('employee', None)
        if employee:
            self.employee = employee
        super(Leave_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(Leave_Form, self).clean()
        leave_qty = cleaned_data.get('leave_qty')
        leave_type = cleaned_data.get('leave_Type')
        #If form still submits, then please put a debugger here
        if leave_type == "Annual_Leave":  # Checking Leave Type and comparing leave_qty against that type of leave
            if self.employee.Annual_Leave:
                forms.ValidationError("You don't have enough Annual Leave")
        if leave_type == "Sick_leave":
            if self.employee.Sick_leave:
                forms.ValidationError("You don't have enough Sick Leave")
        # similarly add other else if logic for other types of leaves
        return leave_qty



    class Meta:
        model = Leave
        fields = ['leave_Type', 'description',
                  'from_date', 'to_date', 'leave_qty']
        exclude = ['employee_leaves', 'submit_date', 'leave_status']
        leave_type_choice = (

            ("Annual_leave", "Annual leave"),
            ("Sick_leave", "Sick leave"),
            ("Casual_leave", "Casual leave"),
            ("Emergency_leave", "Emergency leave"),
            ("Half_pay","Half Pay")
    )

        widgets = {


            'leave_Type': forms.Select(choices = leave_type_choice, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Enter description here', 'rows': 3, 'cols': 21})}
```

**urls.py**

```py
url(r'^(?i)request/(?P<emp_id>\d+)$', views.request_leave,
        name='Leave-Page'),  # leave request
```

**req.html**

```html
{% include 'projectfiles/base.html' %}
<title>Request Leave</title>

{% block asd %}
<br><br>

<div class="container" align="center">
<form method="POST" style="width:190px">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}

<button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Apply</button>

</form></div>

{% endblock %}
```

**error**

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Bitswits 3\Desktop\Intern Work\LMS\LMS\projectfiles\views.py" in request_leave
  47.         if form.is_valid():

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  183.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  175.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  386.         self._post_clean()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  394.         exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _get_validation_exclusions
  354.                 field_value = self.cleaned_data.get(field)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /request/2
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**log**

```
[31/May/2019 12:51:07] "POST /request/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 7906
========Annual_leave
________45
[31/May/2019 12:53:32] "POST /request/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 7906

=======================

========Sick_leave
________52
[31/May/2019 12:54:34] "POST /request/2 HTTP/1.1" 200 7906
```

[image: Annual Leave]

**update**

```
to_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%y'),
                               attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                      'placeholder': ' Month/Date/Year'}))

    from_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(format=('%m/%d/%y'),
                               attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                               'placeholder':' Month/Date/Year'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        employee = kwargs.pop('employee', None)
        if employee:
            self.employee = employee
        super(Leave_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(Leave_Form, self).clean()
        leave_qty = cleaned_data.get('leave_qty')
        leave_type = cleaned_data.get('leave_Type')
        if leave_type < leave_qty:

            print "======== " + str(leave_type)
            print "________ " + str(leave_qty)

            raise forms.ValidationError("You don't have enough Annual Leave")

        return cleaned_data
```

I expect an error either after the submission of the form or on the very page, My seniors have suggested to use JS but I;m not familiar with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [**`clean`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) method in `ModelForm`. You can do it like this:

For accessing `Employee`'s current leave count, we need pass `Employee` object to the Form. So we have to override Form's `__init__` method as well:

```
class Leave_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        employee = kwargs.pop('employee', None)
        if employee:
            self.employee = employee
        super(Leave_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(Leave_Form, self).clean()
        leave_qty = cleaned_data.get('leave_qty')
        leave_type = cleaned_data.get('leave_Type')
        #If form still submits, then please put a debugger here
        if leave_type == "Annual_leave":  # Checking Leave Type and comparing leave_qty against that type of leave
            if self.employee.Annual_leave < leave_qty:
                 raise forms.ValidationError("You don't have enough Annual Leave")
        if leave_type == "Sick_leave":
            if self.employee.Sick_leave < leave_qty:
                 raise forms.ValidationError("You don't have enough Sick Leave")
        # similarly add other else if logic for other types of leaves
        return cleaned_data
```

Now, we can use this form in `request_leave` view like this( we will pass **employee** object as keyword argument in Form):

```
@login_required(login_url='LoginPage')
def request_leave(request, emp_id):  # Requesting leave
    employee = Employee.objects.get(employee_name=emp_id) 
    if employee.allowed == True:
        form = Leave_Form(request.POST,employee=employee)
        # rest of the code
```

Finally, update the template as well to show errors([**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages)):

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}

    {% for err in form.non_field_errors %}
      <p>{{ err }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: No use, form still submitting.

Comment: @nuddra Update template how? also check for traceback error

Comment: @TalhaMurtaza can you please update your question with your updated code?

Comment: @nuddra Sure Please check

Comment: @TalhaMurtaza probably I found the issue. It was bug in my code. You need to replace `return leave_qty` with `return cleaned_data`. But still, I think the form is validating. Maybe I am missing something in here. Can you please print the value of leave_qty and leave_type, and check if the if-else conditions are correct or not in `clean()` method.

Comment: I'll post a screenshot and the log.

Comment: It's successfully passing the values.

Comment: @TalhaMurtaza I have updated the answer again. Please try it again. Thanks

Comment: No use. Form still submits. any idea why isn't it validating?

Comment: I missed that its `Annual_leave` not `Annual_Leave`. Hopefully if-else condition should work now

Comment: No, It's not. I even tried to make it general for all the code but nothing. Check update

Comment: Why are you comparing  `if leave_type < leave_qty:`, can you please try `self.employee.Annual_leave <  leave_qty`?(Assuming self.employee.Annual_leave contains total number of annual leave left for an employee.)

Comment: Everything works until outside the condition but nothing inside it. tried self.employee as well

Comment: Even if I try **self.employee.Annual_leave < 10**
an integer it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you check the value of self.employee.Annual_leave by printing also, check the type of it, using print (type(self.employee.Annual_leave))

Comment: It's **<type 'int'>**

Comment: What is the value of Annual_leave? Is it bigger than 10?

Comment: I tried many things. made Annual leave 1, 10 even 12 and the quantity greater than and smaller than the Annual leave. But no luck. It's like it's skipping the **if** condition totally.